# Possible analytical solution to $g''(x)=\alpha\left[g(x)^3-g(x)\right]+\beta g(x) e^{-\kappa x}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, asymptotics, approximation, perturbation-theory

kind of related to a previous question of mine. I am describing a physical phenomena related to charged molecules and am interested in the following quantity:

$$\xi=\int_0^{\infty}\left[1-g(x)^2\right]\text{d}x$$

where $g(x)$ is the solution to the following differential equation:
$$g''(x)=\alpha\left[g(x)^3-g(x)\right]+\beta g(x) e^{-\kappa x}$$
with boundary conditions $g(0)=0$ and $g(\infty)=1$. For $\beta=0$ this has a nice analytical solution $g(x)=\tanh{\frac{\sqrt{\alpha}x}{\sqrt{2}}}$ with $\xi=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{\alpha}}$.

What I have tried so far: getting an approximate solution by rewriting equation 2 to $1-g(x)^2$ and integrating, splitting the integration between $0\leq x \leq l$ and $x>l$, where $l$ is the region where the exponential term of equation 2 is dominating. I haven't managed to prove the value of $l$ to make this work.

What I did find through some "educated" and accidental guesses is $\xi \approx \frac{\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{\alpha}}+\frac{\ln{\left[\frac{\beta}{\kappa \sqrt{2\alpha}}+1\right]}}{\kappa}$, which is surprisingly accurate. However, I am in no form able to derive something close to this.

This has me thinking that there might be a solution in the form of $g(x)=g(x)_{\beta=0}+c_1 y(x)$.

What I'm wondering is if there is an analytical solution to the actual differential equation, and if so, could someone point me in the correct direction such that I can (learn to) solve it. If not, what might be other methods to obtain an approximate expression for $\xi$. Thank you.

**Edit**: I have some software which solves a lattice-based model for this physical problem and found that indeed for a certain region $0\leq x \leq l$ $g(x)$ is very small and almost stationary, after this point the $\tanh$ solution seems to describe $g(x)$ with high accuracy.

**Edit**: **Analysis of the parameters $\alpha$ and $\kappa$ shows that $\frac{2}{\alpha}>\kappa^2$. In general $\kappa>0$,and $\alpha<\kappa<\beta$.**

**Edit**: For the physicists with us, the problem here is seemingly equivalent to describing the spin order parameter in a correlated magnetic field $\beta g(x) e^{-\kappa x}$ see for instance Lubensky, T. C., and Morton H. Rubin. "Critical phenomena in semi-infinite systems. II. Mean-field theory." Physical Review B 12.9 (1975): 3885.

Comment: Just curious, are your parameters $\beta$ and $\kappa$ supposed to be small?

Comment: $\kappa$ is relatively small $O(1)$ and $\beta$ is quite big $O(10)$.

Comment: A small observation: I think the behavior of $g$ (and hence $\xi$) depends on whether $2\alpha>\kappa^2$ or not. Indeed, considering that any solution $g$ will eventually "decelerate" as $x\to\infty$, we have $g''(x)\leq0$ for large $x$, which in turn implies $$g(x)\leq\sqrt{1-\frac{\beta}{\alpha}e^{-\kappa x}}\approx1-\frac{\beta}{2\alpha}e^{-\kappa x}.$$  This sets the lower bound for the decay speed of $g(x)$, which is far slower than that of $$\tanh\left(\sqrt{\frac{\alpha}{2}}x\right)=1-2e^{-\sqrt{2\alpha}x}+\cdots$$ if $2\alpha>\kappa^2$.

Comment: A heuristics suggests $$g(x)=1-\frac{\beta}{2\alpha-\kappa^2}e^{-\kappa x}+\cdots,$$ but my attempt to find a series solution of the form $g(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_ne^{-n\kappa x}$ was in vain.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your suggestion. I've investigated my parameters and $\frac{2}{\alpha}>\kappa^2$. In physical terms, the potential given by $e^{-\kappa x}$ decays (much) faster than the typical rate of change associated with $g(x)$, as was also observed in the lattice-based computations. Thus, the length-scale associated with the potential are much smaller than the length-scale associated with $g$. I do believe that your approach might lead to a good approximation for $\xi$. I will try some things today and edit my post. Thanks!

Comment: Are there other restrictions for the parameters? E.g. $\kappa>0$...

Comment: Yes indeed, $\kappa>0, \beta>0,\alpha>0$. I've edited the post to make it more clear.

Comment: could you provide some plots, would be very nice to test some asymptotic results (especially if $\beta >>1$ )and the ODE is nothing which is easily crunched in mathematica (at least in the free cloud edition) .

Comment: It is indeed an intriguing question. One easy thing I observed that we always have $g(x) < g_0(x)$, where $g_0(x) = \tanh(\sqrt{\alpha/2}\,x)$ is the solution when $\beta=0$. As such, we get $\xi>\sqrt{\frac{2}{\alpha}}$, but otherwise I have no idea how to tackle this. I kind of envision $g(x)$ as the position of a particle subject to the potential $V(x)=-\frac{\alpha}{4}(1-x^2)^2$ and the external force $F(x,t)=\beta x e^{-\kappa t}$ that ends up at the unstable equilibrium $x=1$ of $V$ as $t\to\infty$, but I am not sure if this helps because I can't translate this to Hamiltonian formalism.

Comment: I might have a way to tackle the problem. Going to work it out this weekend. So physically there is another boundary condition. The system must be electroneutral, thus one may derive another set of equations that might help solve for $\xi$.

Comment: @SangchulLee, an interesting approximate solution in spherical coordinates (neglecting the $\alpha$ term) is given bij Odijk in https://pubs.acs.org/doi/pdf/10.1021/la962109j. Equation 16 is equal to $\xi$ in our flat-geometry case.

Comment: @SangchulLee If a Frobenius solution exists then it can be analytically shown that $$\small g(x)=1+\frac\beta{\kappa^2-2\alpha}e^{-\kappa x}+\frac{\beta^2(\kappa^2+\alpha)}{2(\kappa^2-2\alpha)^2(2\kappa^2-\alpha)}e^{-2\kappa x}+\frac{\beta^3(\kappa^4+9\alpha\kappa^2+2\alpha^2)}{2(\kappa^2-2\alpha)^3(18\kappa^4-13\alpha\kappa^2+2\alpha^2)}e^{-3\kappa x}+\cdots$$ However, most of the time we have $g(x)>1$ which contradicts $\xi>0$. Even after choosing $\kappa,\alpha$ appropriately, the values do not match, so I think this takes us down the wrong rabbit hole.

Comment: @TheSimpliFire, You are right. It seems to me that, given $\kappa>\sqrt{2\alpha}$, the correct asymptotic formula takes the form $g(x)=1-ce^{-\sqrt{2\alpha}x}+\cdots$ for some constant $c$, but the lower-order terms may possibly involve terms of the form $\text{const}\cdot e^{-kx}$ where $k$ is *not* an integer multiple of $\sqrt{2\alpha}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is by no means a full answer however it is too long for a comment and I think it is of value. We give general solutions in two special cases.

1. $\beta= 0 $. Here this is an autonomous equation  and using entry 2.9.2-1 in [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XHTbQ.png) we get:

\begin{equation}
x + C_2 = \int \frac{d g}{\sqrt{\alpha g^2 (g^2/2-1) + C_1}}
\end{equation}

The solution above reduces to the solution given in the body of the question if $C_2=0$ and $C_1 = \alpha/2 $. the required boundary conditions are satisfied.

2. $\alpha = 0 $. This is a translation-dilatation equation. Using entry 2.9.1-2.27 in [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XHTbQ.png) we get one reduces it firstly to a Riccati equation and then to a linear second order ODE which is solved in terms of Bessel functions. The result reads:

\begin{equation}
g(x) = C_1 I_0(2 \frac{\sqrt{\beta}}{\kappa} \sqrt{e^{-\kappa x}}) + C_2 K_0(2 \frac{\sqrt{\beta}}{\kappa} \sqrt{e^{-\kappa x}})
\end{equation}

If $C_2=0$ and $C_1=1$ then $g(\infty) = 1$ as required however the value at zero is in general not zero unless some quantization conditions are imposed on the parameters.

---

Update: I was thinking that one might find a general solution to this ODE by using a perturbation approach, i.e. by postulating that $g(x) := \sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty f_p(x) \cdot \beta^p $ with $f_0(x) := \tanh(\sqrt{\alpha/2} x) $. In here I found the first order correction $f_1(x) $. This quantity satisfies the following ODE:

\begin{equation}
f^{''}_1(x)+ \alpha \left(1- 3 \tanh(\sqrt{\alpha/2} x)^2\right) f_1(x) - e^{-\kappa x} \tanh(\sqrt{\alpha/2} x) = 0 \quad (i)
\end{equation}

Now by substituting for  $u = \exp(\sqrt{\alpha/2} x)$ we found that $f_1(u) = 1/\sqrt{u} {\tilde f}_1(u) $ where

\begin{equation}
{\tilde f}^{''}_1(u)+ \alpha \left(-\frac{15}{4 u^2} + \frac{24}{(1+u^2)^2}\right) {\tilde f}_1(u)  + \frac{2}{\alpha} u^{-\frac{3}{2} - \frac{\sqrt{2} \kappa}{\sqrt{\alpha}}} \frac{1-u^2}{1+u^2} = 0 \quad (ii)
\end{equation}

The solution to $(ii)$ is given as :

\begin{equation}
{\tilde f}_1(u)   = C_1 {\tilde q}_1(u) + C_2 {\tilde q}_2(u) + \int\limits_0^u \frac{1}{{\mathfrak W}(u)} \left| \begin{array}{lll} {\tilde q}_1(\xi) & {\tilde q}_2(\xi) \\ 
{\tilde q}_1(u) & {\tilde q}_2(u)
\end{array} \right| rhs(\xi) d\xi \quad (iii)
\end{equation}

where

\begin{eqnarray}
{\tilde q}_1(u) &:=& \frac{u^{5/2}}{(1+u^2)^2} \\
{\tilde q}_2(u) &:=& \frac{-1-8 u^2+8 u^6 + u^8 + 24 u^4 \log(u)}{4 u^{3/2} (1+u^2)^2} \\
{\mathfrak W}(u) &:=& 1 \\
rhs(u) &:= & -\frac{2}{\alpha} u^{-\frac{3}{2} - \frac{\sqrt{2} \kappa}{\sqrt{\alpha}}} \frac{1-u^2}{1+u^2}
\end{eqnarray}

The integrals in $(ii)$ can be expressed in terms of the Gaussian hypergeometric function and its first derivatives by  parameters.

```
alpha =.; b =.; Clear[f]; Clear[f1]; Clear[f2];
g[x_] := Tanh[Sqrt[alpha/2] x] + b f1[x];
rem = Collect[
  Expand[((D[#, {x, 2}] - alpha # (#^2 - 1) - b # Exp[-k x]) & /@ {g[
        x]})] /. b^n_ :> 0 /; n > 1, b, Simplify]
rem = rem/b;
rem = (rem /. Derivative[2][f1][x_] :> alpha/2 u D[u D[f1[u], u], u] /. 
      x :> Sqrt[2/alpha] Log[u] /. 
     f1[Sqrt[2] Sqrt[1/alpha] Log[u]] :> f1[u]) // FunctionExpand;
rem = Simplify[rem, Assumptions -> alpha > 0];
rem /= Coefficient[rem, Derivative[2][f1][u]];
rem1 = Collect[rem, Derivative[n_][f1][u], Simplify]

f1[u_] := 1/Sqrt[u] f2[u];
rem1 /= Coefficient[rem1, Derivative[2][f2][u]];
rem2 = Collect[rem1, {f2[u], Derivative[n_][f2][u]}, Apart];
rem2 = First[rem2]
msol = (f2[u] /. 
   First@DSolve[(f2^\[Prime]\[Prime])[u] + 
       Coefficient[rem2, f2[u]] f2[u] == 0, f2[u], u])
rhs[u_] = (rem2 /. f2[u] :> 0 /. Derivative[2][f2][u] :> 0) // 
   Simplify;
{ff1[u_], ff2[u_]} = {Coefficient[msol, C[1]], 
   Coefficient[msol, C[2]]};

(*The Wronskian*)
W = Det[{{ff1[u], ff2[u]}, {D[ff1[u], u], D[ff2[u], u]}}] // Simplify
```

[image]

---

Update 1: As a matter of fact one can write down a recurrence relation for the series expansion solution in powers of $\beta$. So we have $g(x):= \sum\limits_{p=0}^\infty f_p(x) \cdot \beta^p$ with $f_0(x):=\tanh(\sqrt{\alpha/2} x)$. Then we have:

\begin{equation}
f_p(x) :=C_1 {\tilde q}_1(x) + C_2 {\tilde q}_2(x) + \int\limits_0^x \frac{1}{{\mathfrak W}(\xi)}\left| \begin{array}{lll}  {\tilde q}_1(\xi) & {\tilde q}_2(\xi) \\ {\tilde q}_1(x) & {\tilde q}_2(x) \end{array}\right| rhs(\xi) d\xi
\end{equation}

where

\begin{eqnarray}
{\tilde q}_1(x) &:=& \frac{e^{\sqrt{2} \sqrt{\alpha } x}}{\left(e^{\sqrt{2} \sqrt{\alpha } x}+1\right)^2} \\
{\tilde q}_2(x) &:=& \frac{e^{-\sqrt{2} \sqrt{\alpha } x} \left(12 \sqrt{2} \sqrt{\alpha } x e^{2 \sqrt{2} \sqrt{\alpha } x}-8
   e^{\sqrt{2} \sqrt{\alpha } x}+8 e^{3 \sqrt{2} \sqrt{\alpha } x}+e^{4 \sqrt{2} \sqrt{\alpha }
   x}-1\right)}{\left(e^{\sqrt{2} \sqrt{\alpha } x}+1\right)^2}\\
{\mathfrak W}(x)&:=& 2 \sqrt{2\alpha} \\
rhs(x) &:=& \alpha \sum\limits_{\begin{array}{l} p_1+p_2+p_3=p \\ 0 \le p_1\le p-1 \\ 0 \le p_2 \le p-1 \\ 0 \le p_3 \le p-1 \end{array}}
f_{p_1}(x) f_{p_2}(x) f_{p_3}(x)  \quad + \quad 
f_{p-1}(x) e^{-\kappa x}
\end{eqnarray}
for $p\ge 1$.

I wouldn't guarantee that it is possible to evaluate all those integrals in closed form but at least one could do that for $p=1,2$ (we almost did it already for $p=1$ above) and then evaluate the integrals numerically for higher values of $p$.

```
q1[x_] := (E^(
  Sqrt[2] Sqrt[alpha] x)) /(1 + E^(Sqrt[2] Sqrt[alpha] x))^2;
q2[x_] := (
  E^(-Sqrt[2] Sqrt[alpha]
     x) (-1 - 8 E^(Sqrt[2] Sqrt[alpha] x) + 
     8 E^(3 Sqrt[2] Sqrt[alpha] x) + E^(4 Sqrt[2] Sqrt[alpha] x) + 
     24 (Sqrt[alpha] x)/Sqrt[2] E^(2 Sqrt[2] Sqrt[alpha] x) ))/ ((1 + 
    E^(Sqrt[2] Sqrt[alpha] x))^2);
g[x_] := C[1] q1[x] + C[2] q2[x];
((# (alpha - 3 alpha Tanh[(Sqrt[alpha] x)/Sqrt[2]]^2) + 
      D[#, {x, 2}]) & /@ {g[x]}) // Simplify

Det[{{q1[x], q2[x]}, {D[q1[x], x], D[q2[x], x]}}] // Simplify
```

[image]

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XHTbQ.png): Andrey D. Polyanin, Valentin F. Zaitsev, Handbook of exact solutions  for ordinary differential equations, Chapman & Hall/CRC 2003

Comment: If one were to indeed split the right hand side of the differential equation it would make the most sense to use the boundary condition at 0 with the second solution you supplied and the boundary condition at infinity with the first. One might then be able to math these solution using the argument that $g$ should be continuous by matching logarithmic derivatives at a certain point $l$.

Answer (score 4):

It is implicit in the comment by Sangchul Lee that you might have a lower bound on $\xi$. If you have $g$ positive and concave then the equation gives $$\alpha(g^2-1)+\beta e^{-\kappa x} \le0.$$
Integration then gives $$\xi \ge \frac{\beta}{\alpha\kappa}.$$

Comment: I also considered this possibility. However, I realized that if $\beta>\alpha$, then for at least short period of time we will have $g''(t) \approx (\beta-\alpha + o(1))g(t) >0$.

Comment: @Sangchul Lee Thank you. I should have noticed that! Also I think that $\frac{\beta}{\alpha\kappa}$ is the wrong scaling. If we scale $x = y/\sqrt{\alpha}$ then we replace $(\xi,\alpha,\beta,\kappa)$ by $(\sqrt{\alpha}\xi,1,\beta/\alpha,\kappa/\sqrt{\alpha})$, that seems somewhat consistent with MM's educated guess.

Answer (score 1):

HINT.

If $\;\beta=0,\;$ then, looking for OP solution,
$$4g'g''=4\alpha(g^3-g)g',$$
$$2g'^2=\alpha(g^4-2g^2+1),$$
$$g'=\pm a(g^2-1),\quad a=\sqrt{\dfrac{\alpha}2},$$
$$\pm ax+\ln D=\dfrac12\ln\left|\dfrac{g-1}{g+1}\right|,$$
$$\dfrac{g-1}{g+1}=D^2e^{\pm2ax},$$
$$g=\dfrac{De^{\pm2ax}-1}{De^{\pm2ax}+1}.\tag1$$
I.e. $\,g=\coth ax\,$ is the solution too.

Then we can try
$$g=\dfrac{f(x)e^{2ax}-1}{f(x)e^{\mp ax}+1},$$
with the equation

[image: Equation]

$$(f(x)+e^{-2ax})f''(x)-2f'^2(x)-4a(f(x)-e^{-2ax})f'(x)$$
$$=\dfrac b2e^{2ax-kx}(f(x)+e^{-2ax})^2(f(x)-e^{-2ax}),$$

$$\left(\dfrac{f(x)}{f(x)+e^{-2ax}}\right)''-4a\dfrac{f(x)f'(x)}{(f(x)+e^{-2ax})^2}=\dfrac b2e^{2ax-kx}(f(x)-e^{-2ax}).\tag2$$